# Can I use "AS" Keyword in Case Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

I would like to create a view with two new columns as SC and NC.

I want to write a logic which compares country1 and Supplier Country, If it matches then I want MOQ to be compared. If matches then I want the Cost of respective MOQ to be stored in View as NC, SC

Is this appraoch good for doing that.

There are max of 3 countries, 5 Moq, 3 Supplier Countries, 3 Supplier MOQ.

```
create view viewCountry as
select dbo.SCN_Vw_ProjectDetailsReport_Revision.*,'' as SC, '' as NC,
case 
when 
country1=supplier_country1 
then 
(
case 
when 
lot_size=negotiated_lot_size then lot_size1_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost as NC
when 
moq2=negotiated_lot_size then lot_size2_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost as NC
when 
moq3=negotiated_lot_size then lot_size5_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost as NC
when 
moq4=negotiated_lot_size then lot_size10_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost as NC
when 
moq5=negotiated_lot_size then lot_size25_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost as NC
else NULL as SC, NULL as NC
) end as SC,NC
when 
country1=supplier_country2 
then
(
case 
when 
lot_size=negotiated_lot_size2 then lot_size1_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost2 as NC
when 
moq2=negotiated_lot_size2 then lot_size2_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost2 as NC
when 
moq3=negotiated_lot_size2 then lot_size5_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost2 as NC
when 
moq4=negotiated_lot_size2 then lot_size10_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost2 as NC
when 
moq5=negotiated_lot_size2 then lot_size25_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost2 as NC
else NULL as SC, NULL as NC
)
when 
country3=supplier_country3 
then
(
case 
when 
lot_size=negotiated_lot_size3 then lot_size1_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost3 as NC
when 
moq2=negotiated_lot_size3 then lot_size2_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost3 as NC
when 
moq3=negotiated_lot_size3 then lot_size5_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost3 as NC
when 
moq4=negotiated_lot_size3 then lot_size10_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost3 as NC
when 
moq5=negotiated_lot_size3 then lot_size25_1 as SC, Negotiated_cost3 as NC
else NULL as SC, NULL as NC
)
from SCN_Vw_ProjectDetailsReport_Revision
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u cant do that, u can only set your column name at the end of 'End' statement for CASE, below is my best sample that can created through your provided info.

u cant do that, u can only set your column name at the end of 'End' statement for CASE, below is my best sample that can created through your provided info.

```
create view viewCountry as
select dbo.SCN_Vw_ProjectDetailsReport_Revision.*,'' as SC, '' as NC,
    from SCN_Vw_ProjectDetailsReport_Revision
    UNION ALL

select dbo.SCN_Vw_ProjectDetailsReport_Revision.*,
 case 
when 
country1=supplier_country1 
then 
(
case 
when 
lot_size=negotiated_lot_size then lot_size1_1
when 
moq2=negotiated_lot_size then lot_size2_1
when 
moq3=negotiated_lot_size then lot_size5_1
when 
moq4=negotiated_lot_size then lot_size10_1
when 
moq5=negotiated_lot_size then lot_size25_1
else NULL END
) END 'SC',
 case 
when 
country1=supplier_country1 
then 
(
case 
when 
lot_size=negotiated_lot_size then Negotiated_cost 
when 
moq2=negotiated_lot_size then Negotiated_cost 
when 
moq3=negotiated_lot_size then Negotiated_cost 
when 
moq4=negotiated_lot_size then Negotiated_cost 
when 
moq5=negotiated_lot_size then Negotiated_cost 
else NULL END
) END 'NC'


    from SCN_Vw_ProjectDetailsReport_Revision
    UNION ALL

       select dbo.SCN_Vw_ProjectDetailsReport_Revision.*,
  ,    
CASE 
when 
country1=supplier_country2 
then
(
case 
when 
lot_size=negotiated_lot_size2 then lot_size1_1
when 
moq2=negotiated_lot_size2 then lot_size2_1
when 
moq3=negotiated_lot_size2 then lot_size5_1 
when 
moq4=negotiated_lot_size2 then lot_size10_1 
when 
moq5=negotiated_lot_size2 then lot_size25_1 
else NULL  END
) END 'SC'
,

CASE 
when 
country1=supplier_country2 
then
(
case 
when 
lot_size=negotiated_lot_size2 then Negotiated_cost2 
when 
moq2=negotiated_lot_size2 then Negotiated_cost2 
when 
moq3=negotiated_lot_size2 then Negotiated_cost2  
when 
moq4=negotiated_lot_size2 then Negotiated_cost2  
when 
moq5=negotiated_lot_size2 then Negotiated_cost2  
else NULL  END
) END 'NC'


    from SCN_Vw_ProjectDetailsReport_Revision
    UNION ALL

       select dbo.SCN_Vw_ProjectDetailsReport_Revision.*,
    CASE
when 
country3=supplier_country3 
then
(
case 
when 
lot_size=negotiated_lot_size3 then lot_size1_1
when 
moq2=negotiated_lot_size3 then lot_size2_1 
when 
moq3=negotiated_lot_size3 then lot_size5_1 
when 
moq4=negotiated_lot_size3 then lot_size10_1 
when 
moq5=negotiated_lot_size3 then lot_size25_1 
else NULL END
) END 'SC'
,

CASE
when 
country3=supplier_country3 
then
(
case 
when 
lot_size=negotiated_lot_size3 then Negotiated_cost3 
when 
moq2=negotiated_lot_size3 then Negotiated_cost3  
when 
moq3=negotiated_lot_size3 then Negotiated_cost3  
when 
moq4=negotiated_lot_size3 then Negotiated_cost3  
when 
moq5=negotiated_lot_size3 then Negotiated_cost3  
else NULL END
) END 'NC'


    from SCN_Vw_ProjectDetailsReport_Revision
```

Comment: Error: Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'SC' in view or function 'viewCountry' is specified more than once.

Comment: I get several duplicate records for each row. I get 3 records for one. I changed from Union ALL to Union

Comment: How can I get the same result without UNION ALL or UNION.? I do not want to use union as it gives multiple results. I want it with simple case when alone.

Comment: use group by or distinct =x, you may try it or i can did it for u =D